# Issue in python code [ configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%' ] using python 3.7.3 with appium

Tags: python, appium, python-3.7

Below Terminal Logs for your reference

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/Utilities_test/test_cases_csv.py", line 39, in <module>
    report_status = email_reporter(html_report_dir.split('/', 1)[-1])
  File "src/Utilities_support/report_email.py", line 27, in email_reporter for item in conf_data.items(conf): 
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 857, in items
    return [(option, value_getter(option)) for option in d.keys()]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 857, in <listcomp>
    return [(option, value_getter(option)) for option in d.keys()]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 854, in <lambda>
    section, option, d[option], d)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 394, in before_get
    self._interpolate_some(parser, option, L, value, section, defaults, 1)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 444, in _interpolate_some
    "found: %r" % (rest,))
configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%'
```

Comment: You also need to provide the configparser code that triggered the error and the config you were trying to parse.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the configparser is reading a literal '%' sign in a string.  The '%' sign is used for string interpolation (substitution).  If you want to have a literal '%' it can be escaped with another '%'. For example, use '100%%' to represent '100%' in the configuration variable read by configparser.

Answer (score 2):

Try `config = configparser.RawConfigParser()` instead of `config = configparser.ConfigParser()`. Source: https://programmerah.com/configparser-interpolationsyntaxerror-must-be-followed-by-or-found-27394/

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this because I was passing a dict with preset values into my config parser. Some of the values had a % character. I fixed it by looping over the values and replacing occurrences of % with %%

My problem:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(os.envion)
```

My solution:

```
env = os.environ.copy()

# sanitize env, % is config parser special char, escape with %%
for k, v in env.items():
    if '%' in v:
        env[k] = v.replace('%', '%%')
        
config = configparser.ConfigParser(env)
```